# Trouble making a clipping mask in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have the following set up:

[image]

I would like to make a clipping mask out of all of the objects above the "Text" layer (so that all of the stuff from the above layers is only applied to the letters), however I am struggling. For one, when I go to ungroup "Group 1" it changes the complexion of the graphics and makes it darker for some reason. Also, when I merge the layers above "text" I get the following:

[image]

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: What? Please explain your goal more clearly.

Comment: @Komental - I'd like all of the stuff from the layers above "text" only to be applied directly on the text, and no where else. i.e. want to get rid of that shape in the background, but keep the part of it that is on top of the letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, here's what to do:

- Place all the layers above "Text" into a group (it's okay to nest groups).
- Ctl/Cmd-click on the Layers Panel thumbnail of "Text" to load it as a selection.
- With your new "master group" targeted, click the "New Layer Mask" icon in the Layers Panel.

This will create a layer mask on the group that applies the group content only to the non-transparent pixel on the Text layer, which I think is what you're trying to do.

Another, similar approach would be to select all those upper layers in the Layers Panel and convert to a Smart Object via the Layers Panel flyout, then clip the Smart Object to your Text layer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like one of the issues you were running into was some type of styling applied to Group 1. Likely Opacity and/or Blending Mode, which would explain why you're seeing changes when you ungroup them.

Example: If Group 1 has Opacity set to 75% and Blending Mode set to Multiply, while both Grunge_textures are set to 100% Opacity and Normal Blending Mode... Obviously if you ungroup them, they would loose that styling of the group. Ungrouping them, and then adjusting their individual opacity back down to 75% and Blending Mode to Multiply would be the solution in this example.

From there you could just apply clipping masks as usual.

But Alan's solution is a great quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is structured in a way that I don't really understand. Overall you can Merge all layers above "text". Remove the mask of "create". Then Ctrl + click the layer icon for text. This would make a selection and then use that selection as a mask for "create" or mask the merged layer above text.

Comment: Thanks. I tried merging the layers and I attached the result in the question. Comes out all screwy for some reason.